# Finite State Automata Diagrams

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine

I want to transform the following NFSA (see image below) into DFSA.

First let me explain how I usually do it:

I join states to create a new start state (old start state which is 1 here and the states that I can reach using the ε*) and then then from this start state I follow what states I can reach following a then b then c and so on. At the end all the new states that has my old accept states inside them will be my accept states.

So now in my below NFSA it is confusing as I am not sure if I can use '015' as my start state for the DFSA as 5 is an accept state too.

Thanks,

Youssef

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will be help full for your problem.
[image]